# Change URL (Access Mapping) of Project Server?

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping, project-server

We recently installed Project Server 2010 in out SharePoint 2010 farm but it is only accessible at `http://server:10019/pwa` while our Sharepoint is accessible at `http://sharepoint`.

What I am wondering is if I can create an Access Mapping in Central admin to access the project server at something like `http://project`. I'm going to guess not since that would mean both `http://sharepoint` and `http://project` would need to be on port 80??

Furthermore, our project is configured on the same web application as the main sharepoint site, so would I even be able to have a URL like `http://project:9234` or some port number? How can I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are in the same web app, you could technically access PWA via `http://sharepoint/pwa`.

If so, you can add a DNS entry to point `http://project` to that server. Then in IIS manager you can add a second binding to the web app. Then you can access `http://project/pwa`.

Note: Because they are the same web app, you could technically access them from either URL.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't see that :(. It works on `http://sharepoint/pwa`. One more question, if I want to make it `http://project/pwa` do I need the DNS entry if this is an internal site? Sorry, not familiar with DNS details..

Comment: All good, DNS can get confusing sometimes. :) Yeah you will probably need to add a DNS record "project" which points to the sharepoint server.